# Permission denied when gunzip a file in Java

Tags: java, gunzip

Given the following codes I use to gunzip a '.gz' file:

```
public class TestCSVDataToMap {
    private static final String INPUT_GZIP_FILE = "/opt/old.csv.gz";
    private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "/opt/new.csv";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        TestCSVDataToMap dm = new TestCSVDataToMap();
        dm.gunzipIt();
    }

public void gunzipIt(){

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

     try{

         GZIPInputStream gzis = 
            new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(INPUT_GZIP_FILE));

         FileOutputStream out = 
            new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE);

        int len;
        while ((len = gzis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        gzis.close();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    }catch(IOException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();   
    }
   } 

}
```

throws out such an exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/new.csv (Permission denied)
```

this is because the path '/opt' are not allowed to make any changes. But I can use

```
sudo gunzip /opt/old.csv.gz
```

to unzip the file. So in Java, what should I do to act like a 'sudo'?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to `sudo` in Java. But you can `sudo` your Java program `sudo java TestCSVDataToMap`.

Java isn't designed to manage OS process access rights.

Answer (score 0):

Start your `java` process with `sudo`

```
sudo java -jar myjar.jar
```

Or, write to a folder you do have permission to write to (like `/tmp` or `$HOME`).